# Align image next to text in CSS

Tags: image, vertical-alignment

I've read through the forum but can't find what I'm doing wrong with my code. So I'm trying to align the circle arrow image to the center of the line of text.

This is how it looks on the site: http://prntscr.com/9pqnko

This is the CSS I'm using:

```
.fixedicon2 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 52px;
    width: 430px;
    background-image: url('http://www.brewer2016.brewerdirect.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/blue-circle1.png'); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

This is how I have it on the page:

```
<div class="fixedicon2">
<h5 style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #154060;"><strong>View Brewer360</strong> Case Studies</span></h5>
</div>
```

Thank you, Stephanie

Answer (score 0):

if you want like this

[image]

then refer this css

```
.fixedicon2 {
      padding-top: -6px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 55px;
    width: 430px;
    background-image: url('http://www.brewer2016.brewerdirect.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/blue-circle1.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-y: 6px;    }
```

and for

[image]

just add *background-position-x :center;* in your css class

```
.fixedicon2 {
          padding-top: -6px;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        height: 55px;
        width: 430px;
        background-image: url('http://www.brewer2016.brewerdirect.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/blue-circle1.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position-y: 6px; 
       background-position-x: center;
}
```

Comment: I ended up needing to just add this to the CSS:
        padding-top: 8px;
You got me on the right track. I will just have to test and make sure works in all browsers. Thank you! Stephanie